# Why am I getting the response "Unknown type java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption" at runtime?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, types, copy

I am trying to copy a file from a remote server to my local machine.  I am passing the URL from the browser into my function.  When I call my copyReport() function, no exceptions are thrown, but when calling the Files.copy function in the intermediate Netbeans window, I get the 'Unknown Type' error for the standardcopyoption constant.

```
public String copyReport(String reportFile)
{
    try{
        URL reportURL = new URL(reportFile);
        reportURL.toURI();
        Path original = Paths.get(reportURL.toURI().getSchemeSpecificPart()); 
        Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\auto\\OE");

        Files.copy(original, destination, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error copying report: "+reportFile;
    }
    return "Copied report to : C:\\auto\\OE\\Application Output, VERTC"+testNum;
}
```

Comment: What does the `import` statement look like?  Post the complete stack trace.  `Unknown Type` looks like a compile-time message, not a run-time message.  Also, what version of Java are you using?  `CopyOption` was introduced in 1.7.

Comment: You get it how? As an exception? Stack trace?

Comment: Here is my import statement : import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

Comment: I can't add a screenshot, but the 'unknown type' popup shows when I use the Evaluate Expression window in Netbeans to call Files.copy(original, destination, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);

Comment: Instantiating an object of StandardCopyOption allowed me to use the static variables and they are no longer being reported as "unknown type".  I simply added this loop to the function: `for(StandardCopyOption tmp : StandardCopyOption.values())
                System.out.println(tmp.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating an object of StandardCopyOption allowed me to use the static variables and they are no longer being reported as "unknown type". I simply added this loop to the function:

```
for(StandardCopyOption tmp : StandardCopyOption.values()) System.out.println(tmp.toString());
```